what should I do for Springboot error "actual and formal argument lists differ in length"?
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JPAPostRepository implements PostRepository {

    private final EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void save(PostEntity postEntity) {
        em.persist(postEntity);
    }
}

@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService {

    private final PostRepository postRepository;

    @Override
    public void savePost(SavePostDTO savePostDTO) {
        PostEntity postEntity = PostMapper.INSTANCE.dtoToEntity(savePostDTO);
        postRepository.save(postEntity);
    }
}
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Bean
    public PostRepository postRepository() {
        return new JPAPostRepository(em);
    }

    @Bean
    public PostServiceImpl postServiceImpl(PostRepository postRepository) {
        return new PostServiceImpl(postRepository);
    }
}

I have No Idea why this errors won't remove.
java: constructor PostServiceImpl in class com.techtalk.backend.service.PostServiceImpl cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found:    com.techtalk.backend.repository.PostRepository
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
java: constructor JPAPostRepository in class com.techtalk.backend.repository.JPAPostRepository cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found:    jakarta.persistence.EntityManager
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
